# "Counting" in an arrays using powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

Hi I'm trying to count number of arrow where two value are matched.

Here is how i put value in my array :

```
            $obj | add-member -name "Site" -membertype Noteproperty -value $sitecode
            $obj | add-member -name "Location" -membertype Noteproperty -value $location
            $obj | add-member -name "SwitchName" -membertype Noteproperty -value $swname
            $obj | add-member -name "MacAddress" -membertype Noteproperty -value $mac
            $obj | add-member -name "Interface" -membertype Noteproperty -value $eth
            $obj | add-member -name "Macvendor" -membertype Noteproperty -value ""
            $obj | add-member -name "IP" -membertype Noteproperty -value ""
            $tab += $obj
```

Now i would like to count each combibation of SwitchName / Interface.

Exemple my arrays can contains the following amongt other value :

```
Switchname=foo,portX
Switchname=foo,portY
Switchname=foo,portX
Switchname=foo,portZ
Switchname=bar,portX
Switchname=bar,portZ
Switchname=bar,portT
```

I want to be able to get :

```
Switchname=foo,portX,2
Switchname=foo,portY,1
Switchname=foo,portZ,1
Switchname=bar,portX,1
Switchname=bar,portZ,1
Switchname=bar,portT,1
```

I'm currently thinking about using another table to count all of this. Any easier way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: `$tab | group SwitchName, Interface | % { @($_.Values; $_.Count) -join ',' }`

Comment: That's working, i knew it could be something "simple". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Group-Object` cmdlet:

```
PS C:\> $tab |Group-Object -Property SwitchName,Interface -NoElement

Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    2 foo, portX               
    1 foo, portY               
    1 foo, portZ               
    1 bar, portX               
    1 bar, portZ               
    1 bar, portT
```

Comment: That's working too, i knew it could be something "simple". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
$tab | select SwitchName, Interface , @{N="Number";E={$switchname=$_.SwitchName;$interface=$_.Interface; ($tab | where {$_.SwitchName -eq $switchname -and $_.Interface -eq $interface }).Count}}
```

Comment: That's working too, the output is a bit "messier" than the other response but it works ! Thanks.